# Handling notification/event in google apps integration

Tags: php, oauth, openid, google-apps, single-sign-on

I am planning to integrate Google Apps in my web application. Is it possible for my application to get notified on some operations performed inside Google Apps? For example, say the admin of Google Apps adds a member to a group (mailing list). I want my application to get notified on this event so that I can get the list of new group members.

How can I achieve this?

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: "Whenever there is some change/update in settings on google apps.." - what do you mean? If they are going to change something major e.g. OAuth1.0 is going to be deprecated for OAuth2.0 you will get an email from them.

Comment: Lets say google apps admin creates a group, updates members of that group, etc., any of such actions should notifiy my application or should I say "any of such actions should trigger/switch to a URL on my application"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer for the moment is that you have to actively scan for changes.

For Google Docs there is a "changes" feed that gives you this info, hopefully one will become available for other Apps components in the near future...

There is no notification framework in any case, but the changes feed is good enough.

This is a real gap btw, and scanning becomes painful and expensive for larger enterprises especially if you have to do this at a fast clip.